# warning: hostname no-reverse-dns-configured.com does not resolve to address

Tags: postfix, email-server

This is what comes up in `/var/log/mail.log.1`. I have absolutely no idea the where domain `no-reverse-dns-configured.com` is being read from. Also the said IP has nothing to do with my server. I can't even imagine where to start looking.

Comment: I have actually seen it, but by the time I was posting, I thought my reverse DNS was fine so I decided it's different. Now that I know better it's safe to say it's definitely duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure your reverse DNS record for your IP address matches your SMTP server's domain name. You can check your current reverse DNS record with `nslookup <IP ADDRESS>`.

You need to discuss configuring the reverse DNS with your service provider.